# Shiny App behavior when Rmarkdown document is generated

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown, flextable

This problem will take a bit to figure out how to generate a reproducible example.  I have an app (nearly four thousnad lines of code) that has analysis setup in the sidebar, then one tab for answering a set of questions that are used to assess performance.  Once complete the user selects and actionButton to submit the results for analysis.  Four tabs are used to present the results.  Once all questions are answered the user can review the results.  If they choose to make changes they can adjust and the results dynamically adapt.

A fifth tab allow the user to generate an html report shown on the screen (within the tab) and a downloadable pdf report.

There are two problems:

1) Once the actionButton is selected and the html report generates, it changes the theme of the whole app!  I cannot figure out what is controlling this behavior.

2) Before the report is generated the user can make changes and all results are updated - normal reactive results.  Once the html report is generated the behavior turns weird.

a) In one tab there are two tables, one will reactively update the other will not. Both use flextable and renderUI, everything is the same.  The order of generation and display does not matter.

b) The second results tab creates three plots based on the table contents that did not update - the first plot disappears and will not regenerate, the other two plots display but will not update.

c) the third tab again displays a table generated by flextable and renderUI.  It is dependent on the data that did not update in the second tab.  This table disappears and will not update

d) the fourth tab is a duplicate of the third tab but using a different flextable.  This flextable also depends on the data that will not update in the second tab. But the table in the fourth DOES update!  I switched the content of tabs three and four and got the same behavior, three does not and four does.  Maybe it is only updating the last tab?

But why should the behavior be okay before the rmarkdown::render, but not after this is run?

There should be no links between the two.  In server.R the results are generated and in ui.R displayed.  For the rmarkdown the variables are all passed with explicit references, and the plots and tables regenerated in code blocks using the exact same functions.  There should be no behavior bleed between the two.

Any suggestions as to how to proceed?

Comment: I'm not sure why markdown rendering is interfering with your app, but I'd start debugging with these suggestions in mind: https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/debugging.html Debugging isn't going to be easy if you have 4k lines of code and apparently little to zero modularisation.

Comment: Actually there is a lot of functional and modular programming here.  I just cannot find anything in the rmarkdown document or its call that should change anything else in the app. 590 lines of code are associated with functions and 840 with modules the rest is UI an server activity and the markdown files that create the html and pdf reports

Comment: If your MD isn't huge, I wouldn't call it good proportions (my server.R files often consists only of callModule calls), but let's move forward. Did you try any debugging approach? Without narrowing the case to one or few isolated problems (or without the code - is it on GitHub or somewhere) I'm not sure anybody can help.

Comment: I will look at debugging to see if I can spot what may be changing in the system.  I cannot share the code it is proprietary.  I have to develop example code, and that is my first problem, I cannot focus the example because I do not know where to capture what is taking place.  I know that the underlying data is changing, just the reactive behavior is not updating.  I have captured the state of the data and watched it change, so that is working okay.  All the Shiny functions are doing what they are supposed to do, just the ui.R is not updating the views after the rmarkdown code is run